# How to update data column when date value is beyond the given date

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a two date datatype(dateBorrowed and dueDate) and a status column in my BorrowedBook table. Now, I want to update the status from 'Not Returned' to status = 'Overdue' automatically when the book is not returned after the due date.

I have tried

```
public void DueDate()
    {
        if (frmissue.dtIssueDate.Value > frmissue.dtDueDate.Value)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblBorrowedBook SET status = 'Overdue' WHERE borrowID = @borrowID", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", lblID.Text);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't update anything. I do want to try to do this via SQL queries but i don't know how to start.

I have also tried something like:

```
frmBooksOnHand frm = new frmBooksOnHand(this);
        cn.Open();
        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT dueDate FROM tblBorrowedBook AS dueDate", cn);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dtDueDateTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();

        if (dtDueDateTime.Value > DateTime.Now)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblBorrowedBook SET status = 'Overdue'", cn);
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
```

What I need:

**dateBorrowed > dueDate (from database value)**

**Update status = 'Overdue'**

Comment: Side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: if the borrowID column is of type int then `cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", int.Parse(lblID.Text));`

Comment: @AJITH i have already tried that and i figured the dtIssueDate.Value and dtDueDate.Value is not the value from database

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with queries?

Comment: "Is there anyway to do this with queries?" You shouldn't even store this in a table. Create a view that compares the current time to the due time and out puts the status based on that. Then the status gets updated "automatically".

Comment: @stickybit how would i do that sir?

Comment: @kemchan, you can use a stotedprocedure. Btw, `IssuedDate > DuteDate`, is this logic correct? You need to compare the DueDate and current date. Isn't it so?

Comment: @AJITH yes, I figured my logic is wrong, but how do I compare date value from database and the current date? so i can use the if statement?

Comment: [Edit] the question, tag the DBMS (probably SQL Server) you're using and the `CREATE TABLE` statement of `tblBorrowedBook`. Then I can write you an answer with the `CREATE` statement of the view.

Answer (score 0):

First create a stored procedure in your SQL Server

```
Create Procedure sp_UpdateStatus @borrowID int
```

`as`

`Begin`

```
declare @dutedate as datetime
select @dutedate = dueDate from tblBorrowedBook where borrowID = @borrowID

IF @duedate < GETDATE()
UPDATE tblBorrowedBook SET status = 'Overdue' WHERE borrowID = @borrowID
```

`End`

Now in code, instead of your query , call the stored procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con)) {
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateStatus", con)) {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", int.Parse(lblID.Text));

  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}}
```

Hope this helps.

Note: Un-tested code and query. But hope you can rectify it.